# Is it possible to install "iproute2" on Android?

Tags: samsung, networking, command-line, termux

I tried to use `git clone` in googlesource's page but it didn't do much. I want to use the `ss` command from the package but I don't know how to install it. My phone is ARM 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install a whole package on Android as you do on Linux distributions. Android does have `ip` command built-in from a modified [iproute2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iproute2/+/refs/heads/master) package. Many ROMs come pre-bundled with `ss` binary too. If not, you can build static binary for your device's architecture from source, or try [this one](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=1395089523397956439).